# Reaction is not being called when store updates in constructor;

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, mobx

I have two stores, and a second store should update based on updates from the first store. The first store:

```
import {decorate} from 'mobx';
export class EntryStore {
    constructor (parent_store) {
        this.parent_store = parent_store;
        this.entries = [];
        console.log('----------------------');
        setTimeout(() => this.entries.push({event: 0, id: 0}), 1000);
        console.log('constructed;')
    }
}

decorate(EntryStore, {
    entries: observable,
});
```

The second store:

```
import {decorate, reaction} from 'mobx';
export class EventStore {
    constructor(parent_store) {
        this.parent_store = parent_store;
        this.events = new Map();
        this.entry_load_disposer = reaction(
            () => this.parent_store.entryStore.entries.map(e => e),
            async (event_ids) => {
                console.log('we are getting events');
                return this.loadSomeDataPromise();
            }
        );
    }
}

decorate(EventStore, {
    events: observable,
});
```

And for completeness sake the "parent_store":

```
import {EventStore} from "./EventStore";
import {EntryStore} from "./EntryStore";

export default class RootStore {
    constructor() {
        this.entryStore = new EntryStore(this);
        this.eventStore = new EventStore(this);
    }
}
```

I expect teh reaction to run "immediately after loading entryStore". however it doesn't, the reaction is not run at all. How come? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have an async in the reaction?

Comment: And if you want the reaction to run immediately you can pass also a third argument({fireImmediately: true}) in the reaction function.

Answer (score 1):

Try dereferencing the length property of the returned array from the map, like so:

```
   this.entry_load_disposer = reaction(
        () => this.parent_store.entryStore.entries.map(e => e).length,
        (event_ids) => {
            console.log('we are getting events');
            return this.loadSomeDataPromise();
        },
       {
        fireImmediately: true
       }
    );
```

I suggest you also remove the async unless there is a reason it is there.
Also check out [Understanding what MobX reacts to](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html)

Comment: The async is there since the function is a promise (call to server), wait for return set data.

Comment: @paul23 ok I see, if you have some trigger(like a button click) that triggers a call to the server, make its click state observable and then use it in the reaction function as the first parameter( which will be a function returning some value reflecting whether the button was click) and then in the side effect/ reaction function make the call to the server and on response update your state with the response data. The trigger event can be any event as long as it is observable. And also include the third parameter to run the reaction immediately at first without a trigger.